# How can we remove duplicate data from csv using php and store in to db?

Tags: php

At-present I can store CSV data in to Mysql table. But my problem is, In my csv file some columns (Manufaturer, ecu group) data has duplication's. I need to remove duplicate data. How can I do this? [image: CSV Format]

```
<?php
require_once 'db1.php';
$current_row = 1;
$handle              = fopen("files/import.csv", "r");

while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",") ) !== FALSE )
{
    $number_of_fields = count($data);
    if ($current_row == 1)
    {
        //Header line
        for ($c=0; $c < $number_of_fields; $c++)
        {
            $header_array[$c] = $data[$c];
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        //Data line
        for ($c=0; $c < $number_of_fields; $c++)
        {
            $data_array[$header_array[$c]] = $data[$c];
        }

        /* Manufacturer title */
        $manufacturerTitle           = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $data_array['Manufacturer']);

        $selectManufactures          = "SELECT id, title FROM manufacturers";
        $selectManufacturesExecute   = $mysqli->query($selectManufactures);

        $selectManufacturesFetch     = $selectManufacturesExecute->fetch_array();

        $selectManufacturesFetchTitle = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $selectManufacturesFetch['title']);
        if( $selectManufacturesFetchTitle == $manufacturerTitle ){
            $selectManufacturesFetchId = $selectManufacturesFetch['id'];
        }
        else {
            $insert_manufacturer     = "INSERT INTO manufacturers (title) VALUES ('".$manufacturerTitle."')";
            $mysqli->query($insert_manufacturer);
            $manufacturer_insert_id  = $mysqli->insert_id;
        }

    }
    $current_row++;
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: First you need to define what makes a record a "duplicate".  (Intuitively I see no duplicated records in your screen shot, so you need to define that logic explicitly.)  Once you have that, for each record in your loop you would check if that record has already been encountered (maybe check against in-memory data found so far in the loop, maybe query the database, it's up to you) and if it's a duplicate, skip the database insert and continue the loop.

Comment: You don't even have to check for duplicates manually. Simply define a unique key inside the database that describes what combinations should be unique and then fire away. All duplicate entries will simply fail to get inserted.

Comment: @David, In manufacturer and ecu groups column did you notice repeated names like "Audi/Seat/Skoda/VW" and  "BOSCH ME7.x". Actually I need only one row. At-present In db manufacturer and ecugroups has repeated data.

Comment: @samsam: I notice repeats in those columns, yes.  But each *entire record* is unique.  Unless the data in the database is representing only a subset of the data being imported.  In which case, yes, those would be duplicates.  So before inserting the data, query the database to see if it's already there.